# jQuery .each loop not looping but does when you console.log?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

little confused, i have a .each function which displays all results from JSON when i use console.log but when i try to output using .html() it only shows one? any reason why?

code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('functions/ListOrders.php', function(xml){ 
        var newOrders = $.xml2json(xml);
        $.each(newOrders.ListOrdersResult.Orders.Order, function(index, value) { 
            //console.log(value.AmazonOrderId);
            $('#orderAmount').html("<b>Order Total:</b><br>" + index + "<br><br>");
            $('#orderListing').html("<b>Order Listing:</b><br>" + value.AmazonOrderId);
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: You're overwriting the contents of a single element every time.

Comment: how do i resolve it? sorry im new to this ;)

Comment: Try replacing `.html()` with `.append()`. Fiddle with it from there.

Comment: Downvoting the question is unnecessary btw. He's just new and doesn't know... he asked the question properly. I upvoted to counter the downvote.

Comment: Thanks Hamza, append was the solution! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You getting only one result because in your loop you override existing value.  Basically you override html value.  If you use [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead it will add values to your existing elements with each loop iteration.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('functions/ListOrders.php', function(xml){ 
        var newOrders = $.xml2json(xml);
        $.each(newOrders.ListOrdersResult.Orders.Order, function(index, value) { 
            $('#orderAmount').append("<b>Order Total:</b><br>" + index + "<br><br>");
            $('#orderListing').append("<b>Order Listing:</b><br>" + value.AmazonOrderId);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: +1, but just add him an explanation why he is getting only on result